# How do i pick out specific strings from a user input?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make the user input a 3 digit number (100 - 999), then take out the 1st digit, 2nd and 3rd and say what unit it belongs to
e.g.
567 will make
5 hundreds
6 tens
7 ones

I've tried mid and right but mid shows me all my units and right only works for the ones
Im stuck on the tens

```
Module Module1
    Dim Num As Integer
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 100 and 999")
        Num = CStr(Console.ReadLine)
        Console.Write(Left(Num, 1))
        Console.Write(" Hundreds")

        Console.WriteLine(Mid(Num, 1))
        Console.Write(" Tens")

        Console.WriteLine(Right(Num, 1))
        Console.Write(" One's")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: First of all, if you want to use `Num` as a string, don't declare it as an `Integer`. Once it is a string, you can use `Num(0), Num(1), Num(2)` to get the individual characters.

Comment: Possibily, check that the input length is what you're expecting (3 chars) before reading the single values (also checking whether those chars actually represent digits), otherwise your app will crash quite often :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string.SubString.

For example:

```vb
Dim strNumber As String = Num.ToString()

Dim hundreds As String = strNumber.SubString(0, 1) 'shows the hundreds.
Dim tens As String = strNumber.SubString(1, 1) 'shows the tens.
Dim ones As String = strNumber.SubString(2, 1) 'the ones.
```

As somebody commented on your question:

In your case since you only want one digit to return you can access the strings char array and return the char at position X like so:

```vb
Dim strNumber As String = Num.ToString()
Dim hundreds As String = strNumber(0)
Dim tens As String = strNumber(1)
Dim ones As String = strNumber(2)
```

Comment: how would i use that with the variable num?

Comment: Updated the example. First convert the number to string, then use the substring function.